# VB.NET - Using a Class to further Encapsulate the StreamWriter/Reader; Most efficient way of accomplishing this?

Tags: vb.net

My idea is to make my life a littler easier by encapsulating the StreamReader and StreamWriter classes, the goal here is to have this class provide static methods that i can call to write and read from a file without having to instantiate objects of type StreamWriter/Reader and so on.

So far, I have the following code for my class:

```
Option Strict On

    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.IO.StreamReader 
    Imports System.IO.StreamWriter 



    Public Class ReadWrite
        Enum WriteType
            Append = 0
            WriteLine = 1
            Write = 2
        End Enum

        Enum ReadType
            Readline = 0
            Read = 1
        End Enum


        Shared Function Write (ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal _WriteType As WriteType, ByVal Content As String) As Boolean 

             Select Case _WriteType
                Case WriteType.Append
                    Using _append As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(FilePath,True)
                        _append.WriteLine (Content)
                    End Using
                Case WriteType.Write 
                    Using _write As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(FilePath, False)
                        _write.Write (Content)
                    End Using
                Case WriteType.WriteLine 
                      Using _writeline As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(FilePath, False)
                        _writeline.Writeline (Content)
                    End Using
             End Select

            Return false
        End Function

         Shared Function Read (ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal _ReadType As ReadType) As Boolean 

             Select Case _ReadType
                Case ReadType.ReadLine
                Case ReadType.Read 
             End Select

            Return false
        End Function
    End Class
```

**Question:** 
Is this a good method of accomplishing such task? What are some techniques i can use that will yield good results while maintaining code re-usability and simplicity; my goal is to make this flexible enough to use easily in other applications.

Thank you!

Comment: I think it limits you further. For example.. how would this work if you wanted to write multiple lines in a loop? You would be opening a file handle, writing to the stream and closing.. every single iteration..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead You have a good point there, i could try to work around that. I was not thinking of this mainly because the current application i'm working on won't require me to write multiple lines in a loop.

Comment: ..but your aim is for code re-use.. you shouldn't be thinking about your current project.. you should be thinking about ANY project :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Correct, any suggestions to further expand this to take on loops as well? Currently, It does make the use of write/read to file a bit easier (without taking into consideration the writing multiple lines) which i definitely agree, would be a big issue!

Comment: I would probably aim for a Fluent interface instead.. you could include delegates for looping or something similar..

Comment: Thanks for the tip Simon! I will look into delegates.

Comment: In my opinion having a class like this only complicates thinks, just use the stream-writer/reader as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in general nothing wrong with writing little helper methods to make your life easier.  But unfortunately you picked a Really Bad example.

What goes wrong here is that you open and close a file for every single little bit of data you read or write to the file.  Opening a file is an expensive operation, on most common hardware that costs around 50 milliseconds.  And it is horribly prone to random failure, by closing a file you give another process the chance to open the file.  Which may well lock you out, your next read/write can easily fail with an "access denied" exception.  Impossible to debug since it is so random and caused by another process you can't see.

A simple workaround is to give the helper method an argument type of TextReader or TextWriter instead of string.  Or by taking advantage of extension methods.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!! What exactly are extension methods?? And when you refer to text reader/text writer you are referring to passing that certain object by reference?

Comment: Google "vb.net extension methods" and take the first hit.  And no, TextReader is already a reference type, there's no point in using ByRef since your method doesn't actually *change* the reader.  There are plenty of decent books about vb.net programming, you ought to pick one up in your local library to get to the next level.

Comment: "Extension methods enable developers to add custom functionality to data types that are already defined without creating a new derived type." - This is good stuff, thank you for the info Hans, i will research this further and go from here! +1

Answer (score 2):

Much of this functionality has already been provided for you via the `System.IO.File` class:

- [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx)
- [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)
- [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)